# Is there any way to select a last element in a Current row of multi-line stack in a block?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example, i have some `<ul>` element with `<li>` blocks floated left.
If i resize my  that way, that to `<li>` elements got place by 3 in a row. Next, i resize window (by mouse for example) and my `<ul>` got new width with `<li>` elements placing by 4 in a row for now.
So, how to select last `<li>` in a every row of that stack of elements, that to set them some CSS rule (margin-right for example).

So i need to know, is there any CSS selector or way to select with behavior explained here:
http://jsfiddle.net/w7PDM/12/

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to calculate the last one, and it's simple.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('ul').css('width','200px');
    $('.current-last-of-row').removeClass('current-last-of-row');
    var itemsPerRow = Math.floor(parseInt($('ul').css('width')) / 40);
    //$('li:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('current-last-of-row');
    for(var i=1; i < $('ul li').length; i++)
    {
        if( i % itemsPerRow == 0 )
        {
            $('li').eq(i-1).addClass('current-last-of-row');
        }
    }
    $('h1').text('Now, every 4 element is a "last-of-a-row"');
});​
```

check out the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jun1st/hK9aZ/1/

Comment: I know that i can do it with JavaScript, as you can see in my question.